CSV airdrop Safe app on Optimism giving error
I am trying to use CSV airdrop Safe app on Optimism.  I am getting the following error.
Any help please?
Error text:

Simulation failed


The transaction failed during the simulation throwing error GS026 in the contract at 0xfb1bffc9d739b8d520daf37df666da4c687191ea. Full simulation report is available on Tenderly.



This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page.
Hope it helps, Louis
